# How to build a decompiler for Lua 5.1?

Tags: optimization, lua, compiler-construction, decompiling

I am building a decompiler for Lua 5.1. (for study purposes only)

Here is the generated code:

```
main <test.lua:0,0> (12 instructions, 48 bytes at 008D0520)
0+ params, 2 slots, 0 upvalues, 0 locals, 6 constants, 0 functions
        1       [1]     LOADK           0 -2    ; 2
        2       [1]     SETGLOBAL       0 -1    ; plz_help_me
        3       [2]     LOADK           0 -4    ; 24
        4       [2]     SETGLOBAL       0 -3    ; oh_no
        5       [3]     GETGLOBAL       0 -1    ; plz_help_me
        6       [3]     GETGLOBAL       1 -3    ; oh_no
        7       [3]     ADD             0 0 1
        8       [3]     SETGLOBAL       0 -5    ; plz_work
        9       [4]     GETGLOBAL       0 -6    ; print
        10      [4]     GETGLOBAL       1 -5    ; plz_work
        11      [4]     CALL            0 2 1
        12      [4]     RETURN          0 1
constants (6) for 008D0520:
        1       "plz_help_me"
        2       2
        3       "oh_no"
        4       24
        5       "plz_work"
        6       "print"
locals (0) for 008D0520:
upvalues (0) for 008D0520:
```

Original Code:

```
plz_help_me = 2
oh_no = 24
plz_work = plz_help_me + oh_no
print(plz_work)
```

How to build a decompiler efficiently to generate this code? Should I use AST trees to map the behavior of the code? (opcodes in this case)

Comment: Decompiling is a lot harder than compiling, and it requires a good understanding of the workings of the compiler. So I'd say that your first step is to carefully study the Lua compiler  or, alternatively, write your own. Decompiling is basically pattern matching; the most sensible transformation of the object code is to divide it into basic blocks.

Answer (score 2):

Lua VM is a register machine with a nearly unlimited supply of registers, which means you don't have to deal with the consequences of register allocation. It makes the whole thing much more bearable than decompiling, say, x86.

A very convenient intermediate representation for going up the abstraction level would have been an SSA. A trivial transform treating registers as local variable pointers and leaving memory loads as is, followed by an SSA-transform [1], will give you a code suitable for further analysis. Next step will be loop detection (done purely on CFG level), and, helped by SSA, detection of the loop variables and loop invariants. Once done, you'll see that only a handful of common patterns exist, that can be directly translated to higher level loops. Detecting `if` and other linear control flow sequences is even easier, once you're in an SSA.

One nice property of an SSA is that you can easily construct high level AST expressions out of it. You have a use count for every SSA variable, so you can simply substitute all the single-use variables (that were not produced by side-effect instructions) in place of their use (and side-effect ones too if you maintain their order). Only multi-use variables will remain.

Of course, you'll never get meaningful local variable names out of this procedure. Globals are preserved.

[1] https://pfalcon.github.io/ssabook/latest/

Comment: How to efficiently deploy this in C++? I found some patterns. Generally, when a table is started, a LOADK sequence is defined (to insert the values ​​in the table). Then a SETGLOBAL is defined (and the table is finalized).

I believe that using `printf ("{"), (... table values ​​..) printf ("}")` is not an efficient way to do this.

Comment: @Gurama You can take a look at pattern matching library in LLVM (the one used in the InstCombine passes). Since it'll make sense for you to use an intermediate representation similar to LLVM IR, you can also borrow a few ideas from the infrastructure around it.

Comment: @SK-logic a couple of additions/clarifications.  Pattern matching on instruction opcode names probably isn't going to do it unless compilation is as lame as Python 1.0-2.3 was. And pattern matching including the operand is not practical. So some kind of tokenization and way of dealing with control flow is needed. Second what you'd need before the AST would be a parse tree. I write about this in https://github.com/rocky/python-uncompyle6/wiki/How-does-this-code-work%3F

Comment: @SK-logic Also the ssabook link is broken as of Mar 10, 2022

Comment: @rocky as for the parse tree - you don't really need it, your AST can contain as much source-level metadata as you want, all the way down through transformed ASTs. See how, say, nanopass-based compilers handle that. And, what I'm talking about is not a pattern matching, it's a substitution of single-use SSA variables as sub-expressions. Even simpler than pattern-matching, but works perfectly.

Comment: @rocky and also, SSA will naturally take care of the data and control flow, you don't need anything else to reconstruct it from a 3-address.

Comment: @SK-logic  I looked at the ssabook and while looks interesting, there isn't a single mention of decompiler in there. Or nanopass-based compilers, but I googled for that and got information there. I am not aware of any nanopass-based decompilers. Are there any? You describe what I call a general-purpose decompiler approach: it work on just about any language. In my experience though, when it is possible, you can get better results making use of the high-level nature the bytecode often found from dynamic high-level language compiler/interpreters.

Comment: @rocky of course, the book won't mention it, but it does explain SSA-transform in detail. How to decompile after performing such a transform is explained in my answer here in detail. Lua bytecode does not expose too much of the source details, so you cannot really exploit it. But it is convenient, being a 3-address VM with a large number of registers, so the generic decompilation process I described will be trivial here (unlike, say, a stack-based VM). Nanopass-like approach here will help to make the decompilation process even more trivial, it works well both ways.

Comment: @SK-logic you really haven't answered any of the questions I asked. Has a decompiler been written that uses SSA? Has a decompiler been written using a nanopass approach? If so details please. In my experience what one imagines might work may vary when you actually get down to details.   Try elaborating the approach you suggest with a simple worked-out with control flow that mixes logic with (short-circuit) "and"s and "or"s and has  a loop.

Comment: @rocky for example, my translator from a stack VM to an SSA is essentially a decompiler - it restores the code to the level of structured statements and expressions before lowering them back into a flat IR. Just try what I suggest on your favourite kind of a bytecode and you'll see how it works, it's the easiest way.

Comment: I'd ask for a link to specific code, but at this point I am getting the idea that this isn't going to answer any of my very specific questions, which is why there has been all of this vagueness, It doesn't look like you have a concrete solution or example but rather thoughts on how one *might* implement a solution. Sure, I get that you think that VM to SSA is essentially a decompiler. A toy decompiler. Since you are into suggestions, I suggest you try it on some real example and then you may see things differently and/or understand the challenges.  Or I suggest you read the links I gave.

Comment: @rocky, I wrote a number of binary decompilers using this method (for aarch64 and for risc-v architectures), so it definitely works and it works far better than any ad hoc pattern matching that you seem to favour. This way you can very easily detect all possible looping constructions, you can rebuild expressions without employing needless temporary variables (the bane of all decompilers).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a lua decompiler for lua 5.1 written in C that can be used for study; https://github.com/viruscamp/luadec https://www.lua.org/wshop05/Muhammad.pdf describes how it works.

And on the extremely simple example you give, it comes back with the *exactly* same thing:

```
$ ./luadec ../tmp/luac.out 
-- Decompiled using luadec 2.2 rev: 895d923 for Lua 5.1 from https://github.com/viruscamp/luadec
-- Command line: ../tmp/luac.out 

-- params : ...
-- function num : 0
plz_help_me = 2
oh_no = 24
plz_work = plz_help_me + oh_no
print(plz_work)
```

There is a debug flag `-d` to show a little bit about how it works:

```
-- Decompiled using luadec 2.2 rev: 895d923 for Lua 5.1 from https://github.com/viruscamp/luadec
-- Command line: -d ../tmp/luac.out 

LoopTree of function 0
FUNCTION_STMT=0x2e2f5ec0 prep=-1 start=0 body=0 end=11 out=12 block=0x2e2f5f10 
----------------------------------------------
    1   LOADK       0 1
SET_SIZE(tpend) = 0 

next bool: 0
locals(0): 
vpend(0): 
tpend(1): 0{2}
```

Note: The Lua VM in version in 5.1 (and other versions up to the latest 5.4) seems to be stack oriented. This means that in order to compute `plz_hep_me + oh_no`, both values need to be pushed onto a stack and then when the `ADD` bytecode instruction is seen two entries are popped off of the stack and the result is pushed onto the stack. From the decompiler's standpoint, a tree fragment or "AST" fragment of the addition with its two operands is created.

In the output above, a constant is push onto stack `tpend` to which we see `0{2}`. The stuff in brackets seems to hold the output representation. Later on, just before the `ADD` opcode you will see two entries on the stack. Entries are separate simply with a space in the debug output.

```
----------------------------------------------
    2   SETGLOBAL   0 0

next bool: 0
locals(0): 
vpend(1): -1{plz_help_me=2} 
tpend(0): 
----------------------------------------------
```

Seems to set variable `plz_help_me` from the top of the stack and push the assignment statement instead.

```
    3   LOADK       0 3
SET_SIZE(tpend) = 0 

next bool: 0
locals(0): 
vpend(0): 
tpend(1): 0{24} 
...
```

At this point I guess the decompiler sees that the stack is 0 `SET_SIZE(tpend)=0` or the first statement then is done.

Moving onto the next statement, the constant 24 is then loaded onto `tpend`.

In `vpend` and `tpend`, we see the output as it gets built up.

Looking at the C code, It looks like it loops over functions and within that loops over what it thinks are statements, and within that is driven by the a loop over bytecode instructions but "walking" them based on instruction type and information it saves.

It looks it does build an AST on the fly in a somewhat ad-hoc manner. (By "ad hoc" I simply mean programmer code builds the tree).

Although for compilation especially of optimized code Single Static Assignment (SSA) is a win, in the decompilation direction of high-level bytecode such as is found here, usually this is neither needed nor wanted. SSA maps to finite reusable names to a potentially infinite set.

In a decompiler we want to go the *other* direction from infinite registers (or even finite registers) back to names the programmer used and here this mapping is already given, so just use it. This is simpler too.

If the same name is used for two conceptually different computations, tracking that is probably wanted. Correcting or improving the style of the source code in the way that the decompiler writer feels might be nice, but usually isn't appreciated. (In fact, in my experience many programmers using a decompiler like this will call it a bug, when technically, it isn't.)

The luadec decompiler breaks things into functions and walks over disassembled instructions in that in an ad hoc way based on specific instructions for various opcodes. After this tree or list of tree nodes is built, an AST if you will (and that is the term this decompiler uses), there seem to be custom print routines for each AST node type.

Personally, I think there is a better way, and one that is slightly different from the one suggested in another answer.

I wrote about decompilation from this novel perspective [here](https://github.com/rocky/python-uncompyle6/wiki/How-does-this-code-work%3F). I believe it applies to Lua as well. And older, longer more research oriented paper [here](https://rocky.github.io/Deparsing-Paper.pdf).

As with many decompilers, logic instructions introduce control flow, and these strategies which are instruction based and that go down a path early on from the instructions, have a hard time shifting these around. So a pattern matching/parsing/term-rewrite approach where control flow is marked in the instructions such as with addition of pseudo Phi-function instructions (or its equivalent). Dominator regions from a control-flow graph also greatly help here.

**Edit:**

There is also [unluac](https://sourceforge.net/projects/unluac/), a lua decompiler written in Java that can be studied. Although there are very few comments in the code describing how it works, the code it self seems well organized and the functions are pretty small and clear. It seems similar in operation in that there is a part that is bytecode operation based, and a part that is more expression-tree based. It seems to be currently worked on and is the only decompiler that supports lua versions from 5.0 up to 5.4.